# How to Convert the Value of a Column When Copying a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have Table1 and Table2, both with columns Name, Lastname, Language. 
I have to import from Table1 to Table 2, only that in Table1 the value of Language is 'E', 'S', 'F' and when I import it to Table2 it has to be converted to 'English', 'Spanish, 'French'.

Can you give me the SQL statement for that?

(MS SQL 2008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
insert into table2 
  select name, lastname,
    case language
      when 'E' then 'English'
      when 'S' then 'Spanish'
      when 'F' then 'French'
    else
      'Unknown'
    end
  from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (name, lastname, language)
SELECT t1.name, t1.lastname, 
CASE 
WHEN t1.language = 'E' THEN 'English'
WHEN t1.language = 'S' THEN 'Spanish'
WHEN t1.language = 'F' THEN 'French'
END
FROM table1 t1
WHERE (t1.language = 'E' OR t1.language = 'S' OR t1.language = 'F')
```